# Haskell list comprehension

Tags: haskell

```
sum1::[Int]->[Int]
sum1 [] =0
sum1 (x:xs) = [x|x<-xs,x `mod` 2 ==0]
```

I need to return the numbers which are divisible by 2 when a list is provided, but the above code gives me this compile error:

```
 Instance of Num [Int] required for definition of sum1
```

---

Also please explain what `(x:xs)` does. Is it '**X** element of **xs** list?'

If we want to get a nth element of the list, how do we get it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've asked a few questions so I will answer them one by one.

**Question 1: why does the compiler tell me `Instance of Num [Int] required for definition of sum1`?**

You've created a function called `sum1` with the type `[Int]->[Int]`. However, consider the line `sum1 [] = 0`: this returns `Int`, not `[Int]`. The solution to this problem is to change the line to `sum1 [] = []`.

**Question 2: what does (`x:xs`) mean?**

Haskell allows you to perform something called `pattern matching`. Without going into too much detail, as there are plenty of better explanations, the effect is that `x` is the first element of the list and `xs` is the rest of the list -- that is, you've peeled off the first element of the list.

For example, if you called `sum1 [1,2,3]`, `x` would be `1` and `xs` would be `[2,3]`.

**Question 3: if we want to get a nth element of the list how to get it?**

A common way to do this is to use the `!!` function -- which is infixed, that is, you provide both a left and right argument just as you would for `+` or `*`. For example, `[1,2,3]!!1` will return `2`.

---

Now, if this has helped clarify things, you should notice that your function definition has some problems. I am not sure if you wanted to work these out yourself or not.

Comment: thank-you oftz for making it look pretty :-) I approve your edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum1::[Int]->[Int]
sum1 [] = [0] // problem here 
sum1 (x:xs) = [x| x <- xs ,x `mod` 2 == 0]
```

`sum1` must return `[Int]` but in this case it is returning only `Int`.

Pattern matching a list with `(x:xs)` will put the first element of the list in `x` and the rest of the list in `xs`.

If you want `sum1` to return all the even numbers from the list provided you should change your code to

```
sum1::[Int]->[Int]
sum1 [] = [0] // problem here 
sum1 xs = [x| x <- xs ,x `mod` 2 == 0]
```

Because, your current code will skip first element of the list. Try with `[2..10]` as input. You will not see `2` in the output list.

To get `n`th element from the list `xs` haskell syntax is

```
xs !! n
```

Example

```
*Main> [1..10] !! 5
6
```

Next time you get into trouble see [**Some Common (and not so common!) Hugs Errors**](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/craft2e/errors/allErrors.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, they answered you correctly, but anyways I'm going to tell you something they didn't :P

> Question 2: what does (x:xs) mean?

The lists in Haskell are made by:
HEAD + TAIL, where HEAD is the first element and TAIL are the others.

> "head [1,2,3]" will return 1
>
> "tail [1,2,3]" will return [2,3]

But there are another functions anyways:

> "init [1,2,3] will return [1,2]
> "last [1,2,3] will return 3

If you are starting at Haskell, check [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)

PS: Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an anker using list comprehension!

```
sum1 = \xs -> [ x | x <- xs, mod x 2 == 0]
```

Another solution for the nth-element question:

```
nth_elem = \n xs -> head $ [ x | (id,x) <- zip [1..] xs, id == n ]
```